# PHP, AJAX Login script not doing what I want

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple login script and I've started with just trying to verify an email address. Essentially, from my login screen I am entering a valid email address and submitting it which should run AJAX to run a PHP function. I've scoured the internet all of last night and this morning trying different methods but I keep hitting dead ends.

To keep it brief here is the relevant code:

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("submit").click(function() {
        alert("This was a test.");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "main_login.php",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $(".message").text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

main_login.php

```
<?php
    function checkLogin()
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass!', 'db');
        mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');
        $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $check);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if($data > 1) {
            echo "Login successful";
        } else {
            echo "This account does not exist";
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

login.php

```
<div class="container login">
    <div class="panel panel-default login-panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">span class="log-h1">Sign-in</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form name="loginform" action="login.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control"
                 name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="float: right;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" 
                 value="Sign-in">
            </div>
            </form>
            <span class='message'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting anything happening. The page notifies me when I refresh it that it may resend data but when i submit my email it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Any errors showing? Did you check the console (*CTRL + F12* on Chrome)?

Comment: The errors I did have I just fixed and tried again but to no avail. When I hit the submit button it does reload the page; however, I don't get anything else other than a refresh it looks like.

Comment: You're using `mysqli_fetch_array` to get your data from your recordset, but there's no error checking to make sure that your query has worked. Also, you can simplify your code - `if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))` will return false if there are no matching results

Comment: Try using preventDefault() at beginning of jQuery submit binding?

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` for stop reload page

Comment: you are missing open `{` in your `checkLogin()`

Comment: None of these fixes helped unfortunately...

Comment: Do you call the `check_login ()` function?

Comment: Yeah that was a problem that I resolved! Thanks. I removed that function and now it works with help from @AdamJeffers as well. Now my PHP function isn't correctly reading the data from my database. It doesn't think the emails exist when they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe due to the fact that your not preventing the default form behaviour of  "submit", despite binding to the click event via jQuery, try this...

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert("This was a test.");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "main_login.php",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $(".message").text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Sign-in">
```

Comment: I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console inspector?